# Let's Encrypt SSL certs for same domain, multiple instances

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I've successfully installed Let's Encrypt SSL certs on a domain instance (on Ubuntu 14.4), but I now want to install the same certs on another virtual instance for the same domain.

Question: With multiple virtual instances for the same domain, should I just copy over the certs from the initial initial (using the Let's Encrypt tools), or is there another better way?

I imagine that you can't query Let's Encrypt for a new cert, or else it will invalidate the first.

**I am currently sharing the certs, which works.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the question very interesting from the point of view of common understanding of SSL/TLS certificates. I personally see no general problem in sharing of the same SSL/TLS certificate on multiple computers or virtual instances. The only problem could exist only in some properties of the certificate, like Subject Alternative Name (DNS Name), of the certificate (I mean the options like ).

The section [3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) (Server Identity) of rfc2818:

> If the client has external information as to the expected identity of
> the server, the hostname check MAY be omitted. (For instance, a client
> may be connecting to a machine whose address and hostname are dynamic
> but the client knows the certificate that the server will present.)
>
> ...
>
> If a subjectAltName extension of type dNSName is present, that
> MUST be used as the identity. Otherwise, the (most specific) Common
> Name field in the Subject field of the certificate MUST be used.
> Although the use of the Common Name is existing practice, it is
> deprecated and Certification Authorities are encouraged to use the
> dNSName instead.

The only problem is that Let’s Encrypt seems not yet support wildcard certificates (see [FAQ](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/frequently-asked-questions-faq/26)). I'm not sure whether the restriction is still exist and you really can't create Let’s Encrypt with Subject Alternative Name (``) like DNS Name=www.yourdomain.com and DNS Name=*.yourdomain.com. Thus the exact answer on your question could depends on certificate properties.

If you would use the same certificate for two server you could have some additional problem with the usage of session cache of TLS, which improves the performance of TLS and both clients and the server can use the same Session ID, which improves the performance of TLS. You should describe the exact scenario which you use to be able to consider exactly whether you could have some issues in Session ID or not.

Comment: You can put up to 100 domains on a certificate, but no wildcards. That seems sufficient to me--it just forces you to list the domains, which in most cases for me are the variations www.example.com, example.com.

Comment: I didn't think about the session cache, which would seem to benefit connection time, so that must be a downside if I share certs, but does the server actually record something when a browser connects that I could share? Or is the cache stored on the client and valid for some period, which in that case sharing the certs would be fine.

Comment: @CarsonCole: Could you post the URL to two servers or the URLs to the certificate which you use? I want to say that one have to know more details of the certificate especially to know Subject Alternative Name. About the problem with session cache. I'd recommend you to make trace using Wireshark where the same client make connection to the server at the first time and then later at the second time. You will see that the client will send Session ID from the first connection. Then you can examine the trace of connection to the second server. Will be Session ID1 send? What do the server2?

Comment: @CarsonCole: I have no corresponding test environments. You asked in your question, whether somebody see a problem with sharing the certificate. The connection with the session id from the first server to the second server it's the only problem which I see. You will see in the traffic whether the connection will be OK, but one send some more additional packets between the client and the server2 (and one have no problem at all) or the connection will be refused for example. It's the only possible problem which could be (which I see).

Comment: I'm not sure how I'd test it, other than keep hitting the server, but then I would imagine that if the connection failed (due to hitting the alternate server), it'll just renegotiate and establish a connection with the second server.

Comment: @CarsonCole: What URL have the second server? The cerfificate can be used from nuku.com and www.nuku.com. Are both server online at the same time? If the client will successfully established the connection to server2 after it made previously the connection to the server1 then you have no problems and just renegotiate took place. In some cases the client could *refuse* the connection. I'd not sure whether the connection will be successfully or not.

Comment: @CarsonCole: I see that in general SSL configured good on your server, but you will have performance advantages if you upgrade nginx from old 1.4.6 version to the current [nginx 1.9.14](http://nginx.org/en/download.html). You will be able to use HTTP/2, which get about 20% additional performance. I want to stress that it's **not depend** from the question which you asked. It's much more about TLS tuning. Additionally it would be recommended to setup [Public-Key-Pins](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/Security/Public_Key_Pinning).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109331/discussion-between-carson-cole-and-oleg).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. There are at least two options:

- Run [`certbot`](https://github.com/certbot/certbot) in manual mode

  ```
  ./certbot-auto certonly --manual -d example.com
  ```

  in this case certbot requires a random file to be served from `.well-known/acme-challenge/`, e.g.:

  ```
  http://example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/-Y5pUBNKdx5GKSloP3RifHzUW3NT9xt1UAloNkHz7wc
  ```

  Now you could distribute the challenged file to all your servers or create a rewrite from all your sites to a single challenge server:

  ```
  rewrite ^/.well-known/acme-challenge/(.*)$ http://acme.example.com/$1 redirect;
  ```

  `acme.example.com` should be served from single server with root pointing to `/tmp/certbot/public_html/` (or wherever you'll store challenged files).

  Have a look at [hooks in certbot manual](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#hooks) in order to script this procedure.
- Use DNS challenge. In this case you'll be asked to add `TXT` record to your DNS, for `example.com` domain:

  ```
  _acme-challenge.example.com. 300 IN TXT "gfj9Xq...Rg85nM"
  ```

  Again, you can automate this [using hooks](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#hooks) `--manual-auth-hook`, `--manual-cleanup-hook`.